# MonoTouch Memory Use High

Tags: memory-leaks, xamarin.ios

I have monodevelop 2.8 on top of monotouch 5 agains the Xcode 4.2 SDK.  I have been having memory issues with my iPhone app.  I have been struggling with identifying the cause, so I created a test app with a master detail view.  I made a minor modification to the rootcontroller to have it show 5 root items instead of the default 1.  Each click of the root item adds a new DetailViewController into the navigation controller.

```
controller.NavigationController.PushViewController (DetailViewController, true);
```

In my detail view controller I've added logic that simply take an input that governs the number of times a loop happens, and then a button to trigger the loop to occur and make a call to a REST based service.  Very minimal code changes from the default.

Just running the example and looking at it in instruments I seem to be up to 1.2 MB of live bytes.  I think launch the detail view by touching items in the root view controller and I get up over 2 MB.  Rotating the display or triggering the keyboard to open gets memory up near 3 MB.  I navigate back in the controller and open a different view from the rootviewcontroller and I can see the memory grow some more.  Just moving in and out of views without even triggering my custom code I can get the memory use in instruments over 3 MB.  I've seen my app receive memory warnings when being up over 3 MB before.  My test detail view is very basic with a text box, a label, and a button that all have outlets on them.  I was under the impression I don't need to do anything special to have them cleanup.  However, I don't see live bytes drop in instruments.

As an additional test, I added a Done button.  When the done button is pressed I go and use RemoveFromSuperview() on each outlet, Dispose(), and then set it to null.  I see the live bytes drop.  But that doesn't do anything for me if the back navigation is used instead.

I'm curious if anyone can verify my expectations of seeing memory drop.  Not sure if using instruments to look at live bytes is even valid or not.  I'd like to determine if my testing is even valid and if there are tips for reducing memory foot print.  Any links to best practices on reducing the memory foot print are appreciated as I seem to be able to get the memory to climb and my app to start getting memory warnings just by navigating around between screens.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to comment without seeing the code for the test app. Is there any way you could submit a bug report to http://bugzilla.xamarin.com and attach your test project?

There's a developer on MonoTouch working hard to add additional smarts to the GC for MonoTouch for 5.2 that I'm sure would love to have more test cases.

I would also be very interested in looking over your test case.